# How to use laravel cookies on api routes

Tags: laravel, api, cookies

I need to read laravel cookies on api routes, but the middleware doesn't give me this option. When i read the cookie, it's encrypted. Can you help me telling how can I work with cookies on api side?
I'm creating the cookie for the user on my controller like this

```
$cookieParams = cookie("params|{$campaign}", "{$campaign->id}{$utm_content}", 2628000);
```

Now I'm trying to read the cookie when I access an api route, on api.php

```
Route::get('/testando', 'API\Checkout\ApiCheckoutController@teste');
```

And the Controller

```
public function teste()
{

    # Verificamos cookies de campanha para o produto do checkout
    $cookie = Cookie::get("params|2920649");
    
    return $cookie;
}
```

And the return is encrypted

```
eyJpdiI6InYzeTQyelJ3N0VmY2JIeHJ6cXBBYkE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoicnMyclloK29lNkhTNlIyaVdwZ2JNeVY0NHl1V1ZBdm5oZGM4bzczXC92dEhsOGRRRmI0V2ROMnNyOXFVQW5wZXNUeXdzNVNQRUJWYWtnMVZTVk9sVUdBPT0iLCJtYWMiOiI2ZjNlZDIzOGE5YTkyYmIzZTg3YTRkOGFlMjk1Mjc5OTMwYjU3MWNmZWI4Y2M3NjY2MDQ3YzE0MmM4ODY1MzkwIn0
```

PS: When I access an route from web.php the cookie works just fine, it's not encrypted.

Comment: Have you checked this answer?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54935502/cant-set-cookie-for-api-route-laravel

Comment: What does your code look like? How are you setting the cookie? how are you trying to read the cookie? Have you tried the syntax described at https://laravel.com/docs/master/requests#cookies ?

Comment: @MiqayelSrapionyan Yes, I tried to add the AddQueuedCookiesToResponse middleware but it makes no difference

Comment: @JamesClarkDeveloper I have updated the question, can you please take another look?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by using the web middleware inside api.php, like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {Route::get('/testando', 'API\Checkout\ApiCheckoutController@teste');});
```

As the web middleware has the AddQueuedCookiesToResponse class, I could read the cookie perfectly